# Retrieving IP address from HINTERNET handle

Tags: visual-c++, winhttp

I am trying to retrieve the IP address given a host name after the DNS resolution. I am using WinHTTP to connect to the said host and I've tried searching everywhere but I can't find a way to retrieve an IP address. I was considering using the WinHttpSetStatusCallback function but I couldn't find any examples that I could follow. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Or if it's possible some other method to retrieve the IP address of a target host machine?

Comment: Is there really no way to see the DNS resolution using WinHTTP?